# aws eb terminate http at https with amazon issued certificate

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, redirect, https, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

We want all http traffic to automatically redirect to https. Here is our relevant stack details:

- Elastic beanstalk single docker environment
- Amazon issued ssl cert

Amazon has a how-to on terminating http in https. You can see it [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/https-singleinstance-docker.html).

One thing you will note in that tutorial, as I have noted in all guides for this problem, is that it refers to cert and key files local to the machine. This is a problem for us because are using amazon-issued certificates, and amazon does not provide the actual files.

Is it currently possible to redirect http traffic to https in a docker EB environment using amazon issued certs?

Comment: Are you using an ELB to redirect the traffic?

Comment: Yes, but I could do it however would be best. My curiosity was just in whether it was possible to do with the amazon issued cert. Ideally there would just be an option in the EB loadbalancer to redirect traffic to https, but that doesn't currently exist.

Comment: It does though... In the listeners section of an ELB, you can set up a listener to direct incoming traffic on port 80 towards port 443(SSL) and on top of that you can select any certificate created with Amazon Certificate Manager.

Comment: Are you talking about the Environment > Configuration > Load balancer? Listener port off and secure listener port set to 443? If so, I don't think this is doing a redirect exactly. I have a site that has a hardcoded link to http and it just times out when trying to load. Or am I crazy?

Comment: You can set the load balancer protocol to HTTP:80 and the instance protocol to HTTPS:443. As long as your website is listening on port 443 and all internal urls are pointing to https, all should be well.